# Issue with python mode in 24.5 on Mac OSX Yosemite: python-rx missing?

Tags: python, minor-mode

I installed Emacs 24.5 using homebrew

```
$ brew install emacs
```

and the [Emacs-Live package collection](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live).  Most things work really well, but I'd like to get a python IDE going in emacs (so I don't have to leave emacs to run python, etc.)

First, I open up one of my python programs, foo.py:

```
print 42
```

and verify this works from the shell:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell`

```
$ python foo.py
42
```

Great.  The underpinnings seem to be working.

Following the minor-mode help (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `help`<kbd>m</kbd>), which shows many key bindings, I now start the python subprocess:

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-p</kbd>

```
 Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun 10 2015, 19:42:47) 
 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>>
```

Now I try to send my program to this subprocess:

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

Uh-oh.  Ok, I can deal with this.  Back to `*Help*` mode. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`help`, find the entry for <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>

```
C-c C-c      python-shell-send-buffer <<<--- that's a hyperlink
```

clink on the hyperlink:

```
python-shell-send-buffer is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`python.el'.  <<<--- that's a hyperlink
```

click on that hyperlink:

```
(defun python-shell-send-buffer (&optional send-main)
  "Send the entire buffer to inferior Python process.
When optional argument SEND-MAIN is non-nil, allow execution of
...etc...
```

put the `point` cursor in the `defun` and press <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-M-x</kbd>, which instruments the function for `Edebug`. Another <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> in my python buffer and `Edebug` stops in this function.  Info-mode has full documentation of `Edebug`,

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`info`<kbd>Ret</kbd>
<kbd>m</kbd>`m Elisp`<kbd>Ret</kbd>
<kbd>m</kbd>`m Debugging`<kbd>Ret</kbd>
<kbd>m</kbd>`m Edebug`<kbd>Ret</kbd>

and I do lots of stepping into and checking stuff, which I won't repeat here.  Suffice to say, I eventually find the offending line inside python.el, line 4138

```
(set (make-local-variable 'outline-regexp)
       (python-rx (* space) block-start))
```

When I try to step into this call of python-rx, Edebug either tells me that it can't find function python-rx,

```
Symbol's function definition is void: python-rx
```

or emacs goes into the weeds and I have to Force-Kill it, depending on how much other stuff I've done in the debugger session.  I try looking for python-rx

<kbd>M-x</kbd> find-grep-dired

```
/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/progmodes
```

(I think this is where homebrew puts emacs lisp code for program modes)

```
python-rx
```

nothing found :(

I find it hard to believe that python mode is actually broken in this distro -- millions would have picked up their pitchforks and torches and taken to the streets.  It must be something I've done wrong.  I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Using `grep` on the Emacs sources will not work as they're usually compressed files. FWIW, I can find a `python-rx` macro in `python.el` via `M-x find-library RET python RET`.

Comment: Also, make sure it's not your starter kit by trying to reproduce this with `emacs -q`.

Comment: @wasamasa ok that was it. Things work with emacs-q, so I have to figure out what in the starter kit manages to kill the built-in python support.  Thanks also for the `find-library` hint -- I didn't know about that one.

Comment: @Dan it was fun figuring out how to debug the built-in elisp code.  Another great thing about emacs is that all the tools for creating emacs in the first place are built-in, online, embedded, available, documented, and that "we-the-people" are "empowered" to debug and fix the thing :)